# Тайланд, мозайка / Таиланд, мозаика

Tags: орфография

Почему мы пишем не *Тайланд, мозайка*, а *Таиланд, мозаика*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По мнению специалистов, слова „Таиланд“, „тайцы“, „тайский“ образованы от названия народа „таи“, которое имеет варианты написания и произношения при транскрипции на кириллице: „тай“ и „тхай“».  Такая вариативность, является не единственной возможной причиной произношения «Тайланд». Другая причина — в аналогии со словами «тайцы» и «тайский». И, наконец, третья причина кроется в тенденции к экономии речевых усилий, ведь «Тайланд» произнести легче, чем «Таиланд».
Сами тайцы свою страну называют Пратхет Тхаи (Страна Таи) или Ратча Аначак Тхаи (Королевство Таи), а эти названия произносятся с длинным «и». А главное,
международным названием этой страны считается то, что записано латиницей «Thailand».
Поэтому, о причинах считать «Тайланд» равнозначным написанием и включать его в нормы употребления следует забыть. Правильное написание лишь одно: через «и».
https://aif.ru/society/education/kak_pravilno_tayland_ili_tailand

По мнению специалистов, в слове «мозаика» йот возникает для прикрытия слога с двумя гласными на стыке. Такое стечение гласных называется зиянием. Эта особенность для русского языка нехарактерна, и наша фонетическая система стремится между двумя этими гласными поставить «костыль» в виде йота.
Однако на письме это традиционно не отражается, поэтому произносим мы моза[j]ка, а пишем мозаика.
Слово мозаика этимологически родственно слову муза. Заимствовано оно из французского -- mosaïque или итальянского musaico «картина из пестрых камней». Оба слова произошли от латинского musīvum – «посвященное музам».
https://aif.ru/society/education/mozayka_ili_mozaika_kak_pravilno

На мой взгляд, мнение наших специалистов в обоих случаях основано не на особенностях произношения этих слов носителями русского, а на особенностях записи слов в английском.
Но плетью обуха не перешибешь и потому словари фиксируют "маЙолика" - (итал. Maiolica) — разновидность керамических изделий, обр. от названия одного из островов западной части Средиземного моря, — Мальорка, или МаЙорка (исп. Mallorca, ст.-итал. Maiorika).